# opening file from virtual machine on Windows host machine

Tags: windows, docker, vagrant, virtualbox

I am using Windows 10 on my local machine with vagrant and docker installed for my virtual machine (VirtualBox). When I start docker/vagrant and my virtual machine is running and log in to the development machine, I get this:

root@dev:~#

I have this directory

root@dev:~/boom/properties#

My problem is how to access these folders from my windows host machine and edit the files that are in there.

Answer (score 0):

Look at setting up a sync folder between Windows and Linux.

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/smb.html